# Android Fragment Manager replace() does not replace the current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am facing an issue when using the `FragmentManager` to change the current fragment in a `FrameLayout`.

In my application when an event occurs I set the `LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` and `LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON` flags to the window and issue a fragment transaction to change the current fragment.

In this case when there is a lock screen the application is raised above the lock screen (as intended) but the fragment transaction causes a problem.
The issue is that instead of replacing the current fragment the fragment manager adds the new one and does not remove the previous fragment so now the UI shows parts of both fragments overlapping.

- The application is using the `AppCompatActivity` and thus the support fragment manager.
- The application is *not* mixing the support fragment manager and the main fragment manager.
- There are no fragments defined in the xml container, all fragments are created dynamically.
- Using `add()` and `delete()` instead of `replace()` does not fix the problem.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this issue?

Here is a sample code to demonstrate the issue:

```java
// called in onResume()
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
transaction.commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Comment: Post your code here

Answer (score 0):

According to Android's Documentation: calling FragmentTransaction#replace() is just the same as calling remove() and then add()

```
/**
 * Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container.  This is
 * essentially the same as calling {@link #remove(Fragment)} for all
 * currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId
 * and then {@link #add(int, Fragment, String)} with the same arguments
 * given here.
 * 
 * @param containerViewId Identifier of the container whose fragment(s) are
 * to be replaced.
 * @param fragment The new fragment to place in the container.
 * @param tag Optional tag name for the fragment, to later retrieve the
 * fragment with {@link FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag(String)
 * FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String)}.
 * 
 * @return Returns the same FragmentTransaction instance.
 */
public abstract FragmentTransaction replace(@IdRes int containerViewId, Fragment fragment,
        @Nullable String tag);
```

So try to call remove() and then add() instead. And if your activity is an `AppCompatActivity` try to call getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() and ofcoure use android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager instead of android.app.FragmentManager .

Comment down below if you still have trouble with this
Good luck!

Comment: can you email me your project? I think it would help us solve this problem a lot quicker @android_quirks

Comment: I can not share the application code but I updated the question with sample code to demonstrate the issue.